# Ternary Operators to "if" statements

Tags: c, ternary-operator

Hey guys i was wondering if there was a way of writing this without using ternary operators by using if statements here is the code im stumped at the times operator:

```
 int x1 = place.getX();
 int x2 = x1 +
   ((direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.SOUTH ? shipLength : shipWidth) - 1) *
   (direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.EAST ? -1 : 1);
 int y1 = place.getY();
 int y2 = y1 +
   ((direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.SOUTH ? shipWidth : shipLength) - 1) *
   (direction == direction.WEST || direction == direction.NORTH ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Yes, you can replace the ternaries by if/then constructs.

Answer (score 1):

A less spagetti version:

```
int x1 = place.getX();
int y1 = place.getY();
int x2, y2;
switch(direction) {
case NORTH:
  x2 = x1-(shipLength-1);
  y2 = y1-(shipWidth-1);
  break;
case SOUTH:
  x2 = x1+(shipLength-1);
  y2 = y1+(shipWidth-1);
  break;
case EAST:
  x2 = x1-(shipWidth-1);
  y2 = y1+(shipLength-1);
  break;
case WEST:
  x2 = x1+(shipWidth-1);
  y2 = y1-(shipLength-1);
  break;
default:
  x2 = x1+(shipWidth-1);
  y2 = y1+(shipLength-1);
  //printf("Your ship seems to be sinking!\n");
  //exit(1);
}
```

If you want specifically `if` - `else if` version, converting above to that should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could turn x2 into a condition:

```
int x2 = x1 + shipWidth-1;
if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.SOUTH)
{
     x2 = x1 + shipLength-1;
}
if (direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.EAST)
{
     x2 = -x2;
}
```

You could apply the same principle to y2, but the ternary statements are a lot cleaner (I think there may be a performance difference, not sure) - personally I'd use it as it is.

A ternary operator is just a simpler way of writing conditions, most useful for adding them inline (as is the case here), the syntax is simple:

```
CONDITION ? (DO IF TRUE) : (DO IF FALSE)
```

They can also be used in assignment:

```
int myInt = aCondition ? 1 : -1;//Makes myInt 1 if aCondition is true, -1 if false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x1 = place.getX();
int x2
if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.SOUTH){
    x2 = x1 + shipLength -1;
    if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.EAST)
        x2 *= -1;
}else{
    int x2 = x1 + shipWidth-1;
    if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.EAST)
        x2 *= -1;
}

int y1 = place.getY();
int y2;
if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.SOUTH){
    y2 = y1 + shipWidth-1;
    if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.WEST)
        y2 *= -1;
}else{
    int y2 = y1 + shipLength-1;
    if(direction == direction.NORTH || direction == direction.WEST)
        y2 *= -1;
}
```

I think ternary operators are a good choice when the statement is small, like `int x = (y == 10? 1 : -1);` otherwise the code begins to be unreadable and the correction of problems begins to be more complicated

Answer (score -1):

in GNU syntax the following statements are equivalent

```
condition ? a : b
```

and

```
({if (condition)
    a;
else
    b;})
```

the latter one is a GNU extension, it is supported by most compilers though. The first one is far simpler to write inline though

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me.  This does work: `({int x; if (condition) x=a; else x=b; x;})`.